# How Can The Current Route Be Observed for Changes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I want to update the `<title>` tag for the page whenever the location (route) changes. I'm particularly interested in observing `App.Router`'s current route changing - I then want to access the View associated with that route and update the `<title>` tag from the observer based on a property of the View.

For example, if going to `/about`

1. What do I set the Observer to observe? I'm having trouble finding a `currentState` property or equivalent to observe.
2. Within the Observer, how can I access the `App.AboutView` associated with the route?

I'm using `1.0.0pre4`

---

My goal is to have a `title` property and an `authorization` property on each View that the Observer on `currentPath` will work with. I want to use the `title` property to update the `document.title`, and the `authorization` property object to check wither my current user can access the route.

Now that I say this and with @Michael Grassotti's answer, perhaps these properties belong on the **Controller** and not the View.  The goal is to gain access to these properties associated with the current Route's context to modify the `document.title` and check whether or not my `App.CurrentUserController` *(that stores a `User` object model for the logged in user)* is authorized to acess the current route.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the properties I'm trying to work with belong on the **Controller** for the route, not the View.

Given some `contactUs` route, it's Controller might look like

```
App.ContactUsController = App.AppController.extend({
  title: "Contact Us"
});
```

My `App.ApplicationController` can now look like

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  updateTitle: function() {
    window.document.title = this.controllerFor(this.currentPath).get('title');
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

So the API methods/properties I was looking for are

- `App.ApplicationController.get('currentPath')` *(currently appears to be undocumented on the site)*
- `controllerFor` *(also seems undocumented, but is found within a `reopen` implementation for `Ember.ControllerMixin`)*

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with Ember 1.13, but found that the reopening the router and observing the on('didTransition') event as described here worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27825139/333068

Answer (score 16):

> 1. What do I set the Observer to observe? I'm having trouble finding a currentState property or equivalent to observe.

You can observe the `ApplicationController.currentPath`. For example:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPathDidChange: function() {
    path = this.get('currentPath');
    console.log('path changed to: ', path);
    window.document.title = path;
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

> 1. Within the Observer, how can I access the App.AboutView associated with the route?

Trying to access `App.AboutView` from this observer would be tricky and probably not a good idea. I'm not clear on why a view's property would be useful in this scenario. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I updated my Question to give more context.

Comment: I have sorted out the other half of the problem. Thanks for the nudge with `currentPath`.

Comment: No problem. Totally agreed re: your conclusion above, these properties belong on the controller.

Comment: Can you do something like this on a view?

Comment: Sure. From applicationView it would be `observes('controller.currentPath')`

Comment: Im setting a property in my controller whenever the route changes it gets updated. However the issue is that on a dynamic segment it doesn't change the route so currentPath won't work. I need to observe this change in order to update this property. The closest I have come is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471068/how-do-i-retrieve-the-path-of-a-route/16471545#16471545 However if I place App.Router.router.generate(['posts.new']); in the observer it still doesn't fire. Any ideas?

Comment: would it be possible for a component to observe this route change without extending the ApplicationController?

Comment: If I create this controller in an addons app folder, how can I get it to merge with the ember cli apps own appController?