# How do I retrieve the path of a route?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Given the following Router setup:

```js
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' }, function() {
      this.route('edit');
    });
  });
});
```

Is it possible to obtain the **path** of a route?

Fictitious example:

```js
App.Router.get('path', 'posts.new'); //=> "/posts/new"
```

Or with a model like:

```
App.Router.get('path', 'post.edit', model); //=> "/posts/1/edit"
```

Comment: Maybe you wanna take a look into the source. The [`LinkView`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js#L112-L117) implements that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your console/dev tools:

```
App.Router.router.generate(['posts.new']);
```

this should output:

```
/posts/new
```

And with a model:

```
App.Router.router.generate(['post.edit'], postModel);
```

will output

```
/posts/1/edit
```

Thanks to @MilkyWayJoe's reference! https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js#L112-L117 :)

Comment: Just keep in mind this might not generate urls for dynamic routes without the actual object (it has nothing to serialize!).

Comment: Yes, that works!  And if you want to add a model, just pass it as a second parameter.  App.Router.router.generate(['post.edit'], postModel);  Thanks guys =]

Comment: Where is the documentation for this? I can't find it.