# Get current path with dynamic segment in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I was wondering how i can get the current Path in Ember with the dynamic element ? 
I know there is

```
@get('currentPath')
```

in applicationController but this will give me only "user.show" and i would like also to be able to retrive path like "/users/1".
I know i can do it by window.location.href but is there any other ("the Ember") way to do that ?

Regards
Piotr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve the path of a route?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471068/how-do-i-retrieve-the-path-of-a-route)

Comment: well no it is the opposite that i want. I need to get the path end model id. so i can keep it for further redirection(after sucessfull login for example)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as the Ember Way as it's not listed in the docs, but the controller's target object contains both a reference to `document.location` and also a property called `lastSetURL`.

```
this.get('target').location.lastSetURL; // "/foo/1"
```