# Ember.js route hook to be called on every transition

Tags: ember.js

Is there a route hook in Ember.js that is called on every transition, even if the new route is the same as the old route (for example, clicking a top-level navigation link to the same route).

I tried `activate`, but it's only being called once, and is not being called again when I use the top-level navigation to go to the same route I'm already in.

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxWjh/): When I click "Test" the first time, the `activate` hook is called, but when I click it a second time, it does not.

Comment: var App = Ember.Application.create({LOG_TRANSITIONS: true }); ??

Comment: @kristjanreinhold That's for debugging.

Answer (score 14):

You can setup a didTransition in the router, exactly how Ember does it for Google Analytics.

```
App.Router.reopen({
 doSomething: function() {
    // do something here
    return;
  }.on('didTransition')
});
```

See example here: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/helpers_and_components/adding_google_analytics_tracking/

UPDATE: (new link since old is broken)
https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/helpers_and_components/adding_google_analytics_tracking/

Comment: Great solution! Works on Ember 1.13.x

Comment: See also this nice syntax for adding didTransition to a router's actions hash: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition

Comment: https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/helpers_and_components/adding_google_analytics_tracking/ Pin down ember guide's version

Comment: Nice one mate. 
Few years after OP looking into the same thing, and this might just have pointed me in the right direction! 
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`Activate` is not being called a second time because `This hook is executed when the router enters the route...` And when you click on that link-to a second time, the router isn't doing anything... As in, no transition is being made (although it is "attempted").

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_activate

The method that I have found to work best is observing the `currentPath` from within a controller. I use this for animations between routes.

In your application controller you can do something like the following:

```
currentPathChange: function () {
  switch(this.get('currentPath')){
    case 'test.index':
      this.doSomething();
      break;
    case 'test.new':
      this.doSomethingElse();
      break;
  }
}.observes('currentPath')
```

You should be able to access almost any part of your app from the application controller, so it's a nice "root hook," I suppose.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mattblancarte/jxWjh/2/

Comment: This does not work either. Try clicking the same link twice in a row, you will only get one alert.

Comment: @imgx64 if you click the same link twice, you aren't transitioning... Does that make sense? If you watch the transition log, you'll see "Attempting transition to..." and then nothing.

Comment: This will work, however, if you are transitioning between child and parent routes within the same resource, which I think is what you would want.

Comment: By definition, the "old route" and the "new route" must be different, otherwise there is no transition.  There is clicking, sure.  If you want fancy clicking behavior, bind it to your controller.

Comment: this happens after transition. before would also be helpful

Answer (score 5):

Did you already consider the hook `willTransition`?

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      // do your stuff
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: No, it does not get called when the new route is the same as the old route.

Comment: Then you would have to do a hack and pass arbitrary values to your transition so that the model of the Route changes. But it seems really awkward that you need to perform some action although nothing actually happened when the click happened?

Comment: @mavilein The activate method doesn't observe model changes so that wouldn't even help. :(

Answer (score 3):

Alter/Hack EmberJS code and add a jQuery event trigger inside the doTransition() Function. This is Best but kind of defeating the point.

As of today, 1 year later and Ember 2.0 kind of out, there is NO OTHER WAY :(

Ember does not provide a way to track route-change attempts! This includes URLattemts(history), link-to attempts, hash change attempts etc..

Comment: It's open source, so feel free to issue a PR.